# How does one find project details on Freelancer.com?

Tags: freelance-websites

I will often open up a project, [such as the this one](https://www.freelancer.com/projects/php/Write-some-Software-9161999/), and see an extremely vague description. However, people are giving bids for the project, so that means that they approximately imagine what it entails. Is there any place to ask questions about a project, or to find out further information about it. In fact, how do I find out more information about the project that I linked, other than the title text and the seven word description containing "payment gateway, chat window and messaging integration."

Comment: It says "in progress", 5 ½ years later. The other options appear to be "open" and "completed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I totally disagree with "Helping Hands" above.

Don't waste your time trying to get more information.
Just run away from projects like that.

I'm a former client on Freelancer.com (no longer).
Surprising to see the level of cheating and scamming by some clients against freelancers.
Vague descriptions "pull" responses from hungry and desperate freelancers.
And vague descriptions allow nasty clients to claim later on, "You didn't fulfill all my requirements, so I won't pay you," while they get some free coding anyway.

If a client can not, or will not, be clear and specific, you don't want to do any work for them.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime it happens that employer post project/job and wanted to share more details about project with some shortlisted candidates only. So in this case you can ask for more details while sending proposal.

You can start proposal like :

> Can you please share more details about your requirements/Project? I would
>   like to know detail requirements which will help me to decide project development
>   time estimation and cost estimation.

Above is example to ask for detail requirements with proposal. You can change it depends on project.